# How to make sure there is no gap between container edge and character?

Tags: html, css

So when you put a word into a block container there is a small spacing between the very first pixel of the very first character ("1" in this case) and the left edge of the container. How do I remove it?

Setting padding to 0 doesn't help, as you can see from the picture:
[image]
Here is the sample to play with: https://codepen.io/alanklm/pen/oNWXerd?editors=1000

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <div style="float:right; padding: 0; font-size:200px;">
      15
  </div>
</div>
```

I can use negative margins to compensate for this, but this would be an ugly solution, which will mess all the rest of css around the box and also for different fonts and different letter the amount will be different.

Comment: share the code, by default such space is removed if we consider the default white space algorithm

Comment: @TemaniAfif there is no code, it happens by default (tested both in Chrome and Opera). I've edited the post with "sample code"...

Comment: body {margin:0} ?

Comment: Why did you set it to `float: right`? Like this there will be a gap for sure.

Comment: change 15 for 05 or FO , then check also with different font-families ;)

Comment: You don't. That space is built into the font...and it's there for a reason, to keep letters from butting up on one another.

Comment: @jona, so it is the easier to see the inner div layout with developer tools. Otherwise the edge of the element would be too close to the edge of the browser.

Comment: @Paulie_D, is there any way to predict the size of this space? Like it is always 1% of the letter width, or something like this? For a reason it is there or not, but my designer doesn't agree with that reason, and I agree with my designer it looks ugly when you put huge and small text next to each other - you can't align them to the left.

Comment: Nope it's entirely font dependent. You can play with `letter-spacing` an size in `em` but YMMV.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yeah, even letter-spacing doesn't change the left gap. I guess I just use and unflexible solution and hardcode the offset.

Comment: You can use `text-indent` for left gap adjustment and `word-spacing` with space in (pseudo-)content after last glyph for right gap, but still, you'd get single static fit for single font-face + concrete text combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paulie_D commented, setting container so it dimensions matches geometric bounding box of its text (a vice versa text to 'touch its wrapper') is not universally possible in plain CSS, and generally even not quite desirable typography-wise.

You can super "hand-craft" style to match precise combination of font **and** text, but unless font used will be super "blocky" and with uniform metrics, it will work only for that single combination:

```html
<body style="background: white; margin: 10vmin">
 <div contenteditable style="display: inline-block;
  font: 90vmin / 0.7em Times New Roman;
  background-color: black; color: white;
  text-indent: -.121em; word-spacing: -.317em;
  ">15 <!-- = space for negative word spacing -->&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

(Notice those wacky `text-indent` & `word-spacing` values.)

Rendered outcomes in Firefox on Windows machine:

[image: white number '15' in black rectangle - leftmost and rightmost vertices touching white surrounding] ("correct"), [image: similar to previous image, but with number '51', now considerable parts of digit five are cut outside of the left boundary and digit one does not even touch right boundary] ("wrong").

As you can see, metrics of (used) font are set for visual balance, not geometric boundaries.

---

Hypothetically, using JavaScript canvas to get geometric bounding box of text and applying data back to style is technically possible, but as seen in the "correct" example above, even then the "rightmost" pixel of the top arm of the "5" glyph outreaching its bottom arch is probably not the right boundary to take.

Answer (score -1):

You might try a combination of absolute positioning and media queries.

Set the parent div to `position: relative` and the child to `position: absolute`, then set the left property to a negative number, like `left: -25px`

You'll likely need to use media queries to adjust the left property value as you scale down.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://imgur.com/ZyDdgF3 . Please add screenshot, or something else to show what exactly have you removed.

Comment: what exactly this negative number must be, so it works for any font?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question originally. I thought you were trying move the inner div as far left as possible. Edited original answer with a new suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that spacing is dependent on the font, and I'm not aware of any formula offhand that would automatically adjust the left positioning given the font family. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!